# Change js variable value based on date

Tags: javascript, date, variables

is it possible to change the variable value based on present date in javascript?

like we set a base date (e.g. 01/01/14) and our variable value on that day be '1' on 02/01/014, the var automatically changes value to 2 (i.e +1 each successive day, something like i++ in a loop)

it will be something like : today's date - base date = variable value

if i'm not clear or if need to put more details, please tell me. I'm just new to js.

Comment: You are mostly clear, except that it would be nice if you provide your attempts to solve the problem you have faced.

Comment: just found the answer
sorry, i should have tried more. lol. posting here for others..

`var date1 = new Date("01/01/2014"); // base date
var date2 = new Date(); // sets present date
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays); // variable can be used here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
var baseDate = new Date("01/01/14"),baseValue = 1;
var presentDate = new Date();
presentdate.setHours(00,00,00)
var timeDiff = Math.abs(presentDate.getTime() - baseDate.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
 baseValue = baseValue+diffDays;
 console.log("value"=baseValue);
```

Comment: For more, you can check:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405721/change-js-variable-value-based-on-date/24405884#24405884

Comment: i just found the same code. my bad. i should have tried more things. and i have posted that in a comment above too. thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

Object.defineProperty will be the way to go. However, if you want to support older browsers it will be better to redesign you code to make that variable to be a function that sets a scoped variable if argument given or returns the saved calculated value otherwise.